# How to enter Japanese hiragana characters to python 2.6 shell on linux?

Tags: python, linux, shell, unicode, fedora

I want to be able to enter the Hiragana characters via keyboard to python shell

I already know how to display them. I do it like this :

```
A = u'\u3042'
print(A.encode("UTF-8"))
```

and the output is `あ` as expected.

But I intend to ask for user input, and the user should be able to enter hiragana characters.

Does anybody know how I can do this?

I am using Python 2.6.6 and Fedora distro.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided your locale settings are correct, it should just work.

```
$ python
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Jan 24 2010, 17:44:40)
[GCC 4.3.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> string = raw_input('Write something in Japanese: ')
Write something in Japanese: あ
>>> print string
あ
>>> string
'\xe3\x81\x82'
>>> string.decode('utf-8')
u'\u3042'
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your awnser. However i have a question. This seems to work but i don't understand this part :  "Write something in Japanese: あ" How can i enter it via keyboard? I have set my locale to : locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ja_JP') but i can't seem to be able to write japanese chars.

Comment: I don't have a [Japanese input method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_input_methods) enabled so I just copy/pasted the hiragana character from your question.  How to enter Japanese text is really outside the scope of Python programming; maybe open a related question on https://superuser.com/ if you need detailed help.  For Fedora, see also https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/I18N/InputMethods

Comment: Oh ok! Thanks for the info. I'll try to dig deeper though. I've just read somewhere about "gettext" module which is supposed to provide the possibility to specify folder with text translation, so i'll try that first but thank you for the links.

Comment: Gettext is for displaying messages in the user's preferred language.  For example, if you get "No such file or directory" in Japanese instead, that's Gettext.  But it's completely unrelated to keyboard input.

Comment: I see, thank you for clarification, I'll try searching for answers in the links you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

They would need a hardware keyboard with those characters, or you could try your hand at implementing a software keyboard.